# ZFS test rollback doesn't work as expected

Tags: zfs, snapshot, zfsonlinux, rollback

I am confused about how ZFS snapshots and rollback are supposed to work.
I have a zpool containing a couple zvols (each made from partitions of a mirrorvdev). I make a snapshot like this:

```
~$ sudo zfs snapshot nvme-tank@roll_test
```

Then I boot a VM located on one of the zvols in the zpool and create a test file

```
~$ echo "This is a test of the rollback system" > rbtest.txt
```

Then I shut down the VM and do the rollback. As I understand the concept, the rollback should revert everything in nvme-tank to the state it was when I took the snapshot, before making rbtest.txt.

```
~$ sudo zfs rollback nvme-tank@roll_test
```

I then reboot the vm, check for rbtest.txt, and there it is, still there!
[image]

The snapshot is there:

```
~$ zfs list -t all -r nvme-tank
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
nvme-tank             887G  12.1G    24K  /media/nvme-tank
nvme-tank@nov82018      0B      -    24K  -
nvme-tank@roll_test     0B      -    24K  -
nvme-tank/ext4-zvol   474G   449G  37.8G  -
nvme-tank/ntfs-zvol   413G  23.9G   401G  -
```

So, am I misunderstanding what snapshots are supposed to do, using them incorrectly, or is something broken with my zfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only snapshotted `nvme-tank`, but you didn't snapshot either of `nvme-tank/ext4-zvol` or `nvme-tank/ntfs-zvol`, one of which contains the file you created. So nothing happened because you were snapshotting a different dataset than the one you created the file in.

If you want snapshots to be recursive to descendent datasets/zvols, you have to explicitly ask for recursive snapshots, with `zfs snapshot -r`. However, you can only rollback one specific dataset/zvol at a time with `zfs rollback`.

Comment: Additionally, in OpenZFS a new feature [channel programs](https://www.delphix.com/blog/delphix-engineering/zfs-channel-programs) ([illumos version of the man page](https://illumos.org/man/1M/zfs-program)) will allow you to recursively rollback a bunch of datasets at once, but you'll have to write a short Lua script to implement that specific function.